# c# JSON Directly Nested Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm hitting a RESTful api and trying to process the returned data. The data itself consists of json arrays within arrays.

```
{
  "category1": [
    [
      "http://url1",
      "URL 1 Title"
    ],
    [
      "http://url2",
      "URL 2 Title"
    ]
  ],
  "category2": [
    [
      "http://url3",
      "URL 3 Title"
    ]
  ],
  "category3": [
    [
      "http://url4",
      "URL 4 Title"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've created a class that maps to the content above, but I have no idea of how to parse the result and extract the individual URL and URL Titles.

I can see how I might do it if these were objects, but no idea on how to access directly nested arrays.

Comment: You could do: `var objectOfYourClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonString)`

Comment: The result of that `JSON` will be an object with three properties and not an array with three objects.

Comment: please add your current code

Comment: Please find my sample code here: 

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KM66mQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Output
{
     public string[][] category1 { get; set; }
     public string[][] category2 { get; set; }
     public string[][] category3 { get; set; }
}

class OutputCategory
{
     public string uri { get; set; }
     public string label { get; set; }
}
```

I have modified your code in the `main()` method to the following one.

```
 string samplejson =
            @"{'category1':[['http://url1','URL 1 Title'],['http://url2','URL 2 Title']],'category2':[['http://url3','URL 3 Title']],'category3':[['http://url4','URL 4 Title']]}";

        //deserialised to my class object
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Output>(samplejson);

        //create new output object
        Output outCat = new Output();

        //I now want to assign the appropriate values to my new output object

        Console.WriteLine(result.category2.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("URL: " + result.category1[0][0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Title: " + result.category1[0][1]);
```

Make sure you **check the length of the array** and then proceed with your result.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for a good example of how to access a more deeply nested array. Most of the examples start with an array or an object and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my codes, after you have YourModel class created then you can  use the bellow approach

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(content,
                                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                                        {
                                           ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx):

```
public class Model
{
    public string[][] category1 { get; set; }
    public string[][] category2 { get; set; }
    public string[][] category3 { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);

foreach (var element in model.category1)
{
    var url = element[0];
    var title = element[1];
}
```